# Delete Rails session cookies from Wordpress and vise versa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress

We are designing an application that will use Rails and Wordpress to interact with each other.  We would like to have a universal logout where you could logout from either application and it would delete cookies from the other app.  They will share the same host and toplevel domain.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: To reach more SO users, you might want to tag your question with 'ruby-on-rails' in addition. That tag is watched by three times as many contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to a cookie is dependent on the domain of the server attempting to read the request -- and potentially the domain specified in the cookie. So assuming the domains match (e.g. www.example.com and www.example.com on both blog and Rails app) either should have access to a cookie set by the other.

If this is not the case (e.g. blog.example.com, www.example.com), you'll need to make sure when the cookie is set in either place, it's set for the entire domain (e.g. `.example.com`).  But this doesn't help: while Rails can delete WP's cookie, and vice-versa, the method for creating (and using) them needs to be mutually understood.

So there's a twist here, since this is a session cookie; in this case, the cookie (which either app should have access to) is setting a value that is used and interpreted on the server side, where sessions are managed.  WordPress and Rails both different methods and look for different cookies.

A solution (idea) would be to have one or the other subsystem catch incoming requests (most likely WP, and probably through some `.htaccess` RewriteRule, assuming you're using Apache) and create an intermediate cookie that the other could check that provides sufficient proof that the user has logged in correctly.  WP's PHP for this is pretty good, and easily extended -- you just need to create some token that's a shared secret between the two apps (one of the values in `wp-config.php` such as `LOGGED_IN_KEY` might be a good option).

Maybe a solution would be to take the publicly available value from the WP cookie for username, and append the shared secret value and (in both systems) create an MD5 hash to store in a cookie.  In this case, Rails' authentication would subordinate to WP's, so you would need to make sure Rails knew to delegate things like forgotten password, changed password, etc, to WP's mechanisms.

Obviously I am thinking aloud, but maybe this is a path to consider.

In any case, this is preferable to having both systems know how to trust the other's authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply.  WP will handle all the auth and forgotten password stuff.   I've been able to get both sides to place the cookies at the top level domain but I cant get the cookies deleted.  Ive tried cookies.delete and reset_session, but neither get rid of the cookie.

Comment: You may be running into some code in WP or Rails (or both) intended to ensure security and/or privacy.  Not sure why, or if that's right.  Chances are you'll end up having to run all requests and authentication through one or the other system and passing off authenticated users to the subordinate.  This might also be cleaner from an architectural standpoint -- you really only want one copy of the user and auth data if you can swing it.  Lots of work.  No fun.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling with cookie deletion appears to be dirty and error prone.

You might rather want to have a look at auth providers and the according plugins such as:

- OAuth ([WP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/oauth) - [Rails](https://rubygems.org/search?query=oauth); maybe make either side an OAuth provider)
- CAS ([WP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/cas) - [Rails](https://rubygems.org/search?query=cas%20auth))
- LDAP ([WP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/ldap) - [Rails](https://rubygems.org/search?query=ldap))
- ...

Maybe it's an option to switch from WP to one of Rail's CMS like:

- [Refinery CMS](http://www.refinerycms.com/)
- [Typo](http://fdv.github.com/typo/)
- ...